# How a function is getting called with correct request & response objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a piece of code:

```
var http = require('http');
function createApplication() {
    let app = function(req,res,next) {
        console.log("hello")
    };

    return app;
}

app = createApplication();

app.listen = function listen() {
    var server = http.createServer(this);
    return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Nothing fancy here. But when I run this code and go to `localhost:3000`, I can see `hello` is getting printed. I'm not sure how this function is getting called at all. Also, the function receives the `req` & `res` objects as well. Not sure whats happening here.

Comment: This is why you don't mindlessly follow online guides.  If you have an actual question to ask, edit your question to ask it, otherwise, this is unusable in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.createServer()` has a couple optional arguments. One being `requestListener` which is

> https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener
>
> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the
>   'request' event.

Since you call your `listen()` like so `app.listen()`, `this` inside that function is going to be a reference to the function you made and returned in `createApplication`. So you are basically doing:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res,next) {
  console.log("hello")
});
```

Hence your function is added as a callback for any request, and thus why any request you make will create a console log of *hello*.

If you want an equivalent more straight forward example

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request',function(req,res,next) {
  //callback anytime a request is made
  console.log("hello")
});
server.listen(3000);
```